# what are java middleware technologies

Tags: java, ejb, middleware

What technologies can we name as 'Java Middleware'?

If I say `JMS`, `WS` is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. The answers below cover various implementation framework to the concepts you have mentioned.

Comment: Middle ware is kind of framework on top of which you can create other application(Domain applications in Domain Driven Design). Best example is any SOA architecture that is used to build requirement specific services. It can build from mixture of JMS(as ESB), any BPM (like jBPM, Drools Flows), some persistence layes(hibernate) etc. Middle ware can provide all basic services like User management, persistence layer etc.

Answer (score 11):

It is not complete.  I can think of a number of other technologies that fall into the Java middleware space:

- EJB
- RMI
- Jini
- Corba / IIOP
- Http + XML or JSON (aka AJAX)
- various "data binding" technologies
- aspects of various persistence technologies

plus various proprietary middleware products like MQ, ICE, and so on.